# handling Null for bigdecimal

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bigdecimal

My code looks like below,

```
caseX caseXObj = caseXBo.getCaseXDao().findCaseXBySID(selectedID);

if(caseXObj != null && caseXObj.getCaseInGrossAmt() != null){

} else {
    caseXObj.setCaseAmt(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

I have handled NUll pointer for the caseX and also for getter and when null set the bigdeciaml to a default ZERO value. Still I get Null pointer exception in the setter line.Any suggestions?

Comment: It's in the `else` block. So `caseXObj` is `null`

Comment: getting exception @     caseXObj.setCaseAmt(BigDecimal.ZERO);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite possible that `caseXObj` is `null`, so it'll cause the `NullPointerException`. You should test the three cases like this:

```
caseX caseXObj = caseXBo.getCaseXDao().findCaseXBySID(selectedID);
if (caseXObj != null && caseXObj.getCaseInGrossAmt() != null) {
    // do something with caseXObj 
} else if (caseXObj == null) {
    // initialize caseXObj, you were misssing this case!
} else {
    caseXObj.setCaseAmt(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

In essence, the error was that you were testing for only two cases - and there are three of them.

Comment: Not only possible, but mandatory, it will always be null in his example.

Comment: @Pescis not necessarily. It depends on the value returned by `aseXBo.getCaseXDao().findCaseXBySID(selectedID)`, which might or might not be `null`

Comment: Yes, but then he will never go to the `setCaseAmt()`. Either way good example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is OK for getCaseXDao() to return null, you need to assign to caseXObj rather than use it as a pointer in the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

That because you don't check for null in your else part.

It should be:

```
caseX caseXObj = caseXBo.getCaseXDao().findCaseXBySID(selectedID);

if(caseXObj != null && caseXObj.getCaseInGrossAmt() != null)
{
//...
}
else
{
  if (caseXObj != null)
  {
    caseXObj.setCaseAmt(BigDecimal.ZERO);
  }
}
```